# Java Properties Class adding characters when URL is entered

Tags: java, properties, escaping

It seems that when you enter a URL as a value for the Properties class, it does not take it as a literal string.

Here is some code:

```
package sandbox2;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Sandbox2
{
    static Scanner keyboard;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties p = new Properties()
        {
            @Override
            public synchronized Enumeration<Object> keys()
            {
                return Collections.enumeration(new TreeSet<>(super.keySet()));
            }
        };


        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            String s = askForProperty("Enter value for " + i + ": ");
            p.setProperty("Website." + i, s);
        }

        try
        {
            String fileLocation = "C:\\Test\\test.properties";
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
            p.store(f, null);
            f.close();
            System.out.println("Saved file at: " + fileLocation);
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
        keyboard.close();


    }

    private static String askForProperty(String message)
    {
        System.out.print(message);
        return keyboard.nextLine();
    }
}
```

The following is the program output, as well as my keyboard input:

```
run:
Enter value for 0: http://www.gmail.com
Enter value for 1: http://www.google.com/
Enter value for 2: http://www.stackoverflow.com/
Saved file at: C:\Test\test.properties
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 24 seconds)
```

Contents of the .properties file are as follows:

```
#Tue Feb 11 13:09:31 CST 2014
Website.0=http\://www.gmail.com
Website.1=http\://www.google.com/
Website.2=http\://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

Why is it adding the extra forward slash? Is there some reason it needs to "escape" the colon character? How could i get the Properties class to interpret my string literally, without adding characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters in `:` and `=` are used as key/value separators. They can be used in the key as long as they are escaped with a `\` (aka a backslash). From the [`java.util.Properties` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the first unescaped '=', ':', or white space character other than a line terminator. All of these key termination characters may be included in the key by escaping them with a preceding backslash character

They don't really need to be escaped in the value, but it is fine if they are. The implementation of `java.util.Properties` probably does this either to play it safe, or because it made the code simpler.

In any case, your implication that it is not interpreting your strings literally isn't really correct. If you read the file back in with `java.util.Properties` you will get your strings back without any extra backslashes.

Comment: I had manually created a .properties file by editing in notepad and had put the url more literally. This was able to be loaded just fine. It's just a bit annoying that automatically creating a file using the Properties class doesn't have similar behavior, when it is supported to not escape the colon.

Answer (score 0):

The `Properties` file *does* interpret your string literally. You can test that using `equals()` for example. The `.properties` file format has to escape the semicolon, but that wont affect your code if you manipulate Properties in Java.